# How to add a new language in WSO2 identity server email templates

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'am on the page Email Templates of Wso2 identity server. I would like to select an other language than the only one proposed (English - united states). 
[image]
I managed to make the "locality" claim required for each user registration, but that does not affect email templates. Does anyone know how to add another language for email templates ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new email template for the new language, under the desired email template type.

For an example, if you want to add a new email template for Account Confirmation, just create a new email template for account confirmation, under the type "AccountConfirmation".

1. Login to the wso2is management console.
2. Click Add email templates.
3. Click Add under email templates.
4. Select Add email template.
5. Create an email for the type AccountConfirmation and with the desired language.
6. Go back to the management console. Select List under email templates.
7. The newly added template will be visible for the desired language, for AccountConfirmation.

[image]